# Cut out the part of the ViewBox. PyQtGraph

Tags: pyqtgraph

I need to display a graph that breaks on the x-axis in multiple places.

Since the interruption range (empty space) is significant, screen space is not used efficiently.

I would like to cut out parts of the ViewBox that are missing a graph. Is it possible?

I have prepared a [picture](https://i.ibb.co/VD6gXkW/cut.jpg) illustrating what I want to do. In this picture, the graph is missing in the range from 3 to 7 on the x-axis. I want to cut out the part of the ViewBox between 3.5 and 6.5 on the x-axis.

[image: picture]

Here is the minimum code for testing:

```python
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        x1 = [1,2,3]
        y1 = [30,27,34]
        self.plotDataItem1=pg.PlotDataItem()
        self.graphWidget.addItem(self.plotDataItem1)
        self.plotDataItem1.setData(x1, y1)

        x2 = [7,8,9,10]
        y2 = [29,32,35,45]
        self.plotDataItem2=pg.PlotDataItem()
        self.graphWidget.addItem(self.plotDataItem2)
        self.plotDataItem2.setData(x2, y2)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. Pyqtgraph uses viewbox to determine dimensions of the axis. It depends on how complex is your application, but I would use custom ticks to achieve what you want.
First, use continuous x values `1 to n` and then use specific tick labels for x axis values.

Here is working example producing result you want:

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph as pg


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        bottom_axis = pg.AxisItem("bottom")
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'bottom': bottom_axis})
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        x1 = [1, 2, 3]
        x1_labels = ["1", "2", "3"]
        y1 = [30, 27, 34]
        self.plotDataItem1 = pg.PlotDataItem()
        self.graphWidget.addItem(self.plotDataItem1)
        self.plotDataItem1.setData(x1, y1)

        x2 = [4, 5, 6, 7]
        x2_labels = ["7", "8", "9", "10"]
        y2 = [29, 32, 35, 45]
        self.plotDataItem2 = pg.PlotDataItem()
        self.graphWidget.addItem(self.plotDataItem2)
        self.plotDataItem2.setData(x2, y2)

        # Set custom ticks [(x1_value, x1_tick_label), (x2_value, x2_tick_label), ...]
        # See docs at: https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/graphicsItems/axisitem.html#pyqtgraph.AxisItem.setTicks
        ticks = list(zip(x1, x1_labels)) + list(zip(x2, x2_labels))
        bottom_axis.setTicks([ticks])


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

I believe you can use more robust solution with `linkView` ([link to the doc](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/graphicsItems/axisitem.html#pyqtgraph.AxisItem.linkToView)) attribute of `AxisItem`, but that would require more understanding of pyqtgraph.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
At the moment, I solved this problem in the way you write. I used range(len(listOfXCoordinates)) as the x-coordinates when plotting the graph, and then created a descendant of the AxisItem class in which I overridden the tickStrings method to extract the value from the listOfXCoordinates array and turn it into tick.

Comment: But, I would not call it a solution to the problem, I would call it a workaround, since this method only works if the distance between the points is the same, but what if the distance between the points is different? But what if I need to draw another line on this chart with coordinates: x1=7.5, x2=8.7 ? So the question remains open.

Comment: I think this task can be fully solved by overriding the method that converts real coordinates to screen coordinates, then it will be possible to move parts of the ViewBox, as I showed in my picture. Also, in this case, I will need to override the method that does the reverse work so that mouse events work correctly. And, I think, it will also be necessary to override the method that calculates boundingRect. But, I don't know the pyqtgraph architecture well enough to implement this, so I hope I don't have to face such a task.

Comment: I fully agree with you, this is just a workaround. I might look into this a bit more in the future, since it's quite interesting problem.